# Not able to run Flask application after I added a second route

Tags: flask

I'm a new in the Flask framework. Already written a few apps, but I faced with a problem recently.
In case I add a second @app.route decorator app.run stop working(app.run(debug=True)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'run'), indentations look good, like in my other working apps. Already tried to re-create virtualenv. Could you please take a look?

`    from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/imgapp')
def app():
    return render_template('img_app.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call your function "app", as you have set at the top

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Flask gets confused by this when app is then reassigned as a function. Just change the function name to anything else.

Answer (score -1):

You have reassigned the Flask App from `app = Flask(__name__)` with a function.

```
@app.route('/imgapp')
def app():
    return render_template('img_app.html')
```

Now, your code is trying to call the `run` method on the function, which doesn't exist. Next time, beware of overriding the variables .